# Stuck in a while loop after forking

Tags: c, pipe, fork

Im trying to solve this exercise:
"make a program that receives as argument 2 other programs (ex:"flow ls wc"). It should run both programs, using the output of the 1st program as the input of the 2nd and measure the amount of data sent. Print that amount every second on your stdout."

I have this:

```
int fluxo = 0;

void fa(){
    printf("\nFlux: %d\n", fluxo);
    fluxo = 0;
    alarm(1);
}


int main(int argc,char **argv){
    int pd[2];
    pid_t p;
    pipe(pd);
    char *buf;
    signal(SIGALRM,fa);
    alarm(1);

    if( (p=fork())==0 ){    
        close(pd[0]);
        dup2(pd[1],1);
        close(pd[1]);
        execlp(argv[1],argv[1],NULL);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else{
        wait(NULL);
        while(read(pd[0],&buf,1)==1)
            fluxo++;
        close(pd[1]);
        dup2(pd[0],0);
        close(pd[0]);
        execlp(argv[2],argv[2],NULL);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I'm using that while loop to measure the amount of data. However i'm getting stuck on that while even after the execlp in the child process sent it's data, and therefore it's not executing the 2nd program.. It's stuck the while loop even after reading all of the data in the pipe.. Why?

Comment: `char *buf; while(read(pd[0],&buf,1)==1)` Not bad, but smells. Do you mean `char buf;`?

Comment: Can't use read if that "buf" is a char. man read gives read(int fildes, void *buf, size_t nbyte);

Comment: @MikeCAT That's beyond a code smell, it's certainly bad in my book. :)

Comment: @unwind How would you do it?

Comment: How do you know the call to `fork()` succeeded?  You're not checking any return values for errors.

Comment: @ohiohai: Based on your comment above I'd recommend you to get back to the pointers chapter in your text book and try even simpler code at first.

Comment: @ohiohai Not declare `buf` a pointer since you're using it as a buffer (as the name implies). I'd probably go for `char buf[1024]; ... read(pd[0], buf, sizeof buf)` since I imagine a larger buffer can be good for performance here.

Comment: @olivecoder Sorry, autocomplete fail. I've edited.

Comment: @MikeCAT you're right, that's what i meant. Copied some code from another exercise and ended up confused.

Comment: @unwind like i said before, you guys are right. that didn't need to be a pointer at all, copied code and got confused. I suppose there's a lesson there lol. The reason i didn't use an array was because i'm not sure if the amount of data read would be bigger then my array. This is however a simple exercise, so no biggie either way. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are declaring `char* buf`, but your pointer isn't allocated. I think you meant to use `char buf` (since you are using `&buf` in the read).

Your while loop isn't stucked, the call to `read` is. In fact, your parent process still has `pd[1]` descriptor opened when you are calling `read`function. So when your buffer is empty, it will wait.

You should replace this :

```
else{
        wait(NULL);
        while(read(pd[0],&buf,1)==1)
            fluxo++;
        close(pd[1]);
        dup2(pd[0],0);
        close(pd[0]);
        execlp(argv[2],argv[2],NULL);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

by this :

```
else{
        close(pd[1]);
        wait(NULL);
        while(read(pd[0],&buf,1)==1)
            fluxo++;
        dup2(pd[0],0);
        close(pd[0]);
        execlp(argv[2],argv[2],NULL);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

**EDIT:
Note:**
Reading byte per byte is not efficient, you will get better performance with a larger buffer. For example:
`char buf[1024]`

and your loop :

```
for(;;){
    ssize_t rd = read(pd[0], buf, 1024);
    if(rd==-1){
     perror("Reading");
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(rd==0) break;
    fluxo+=rd;
}
```

Comment: char buf is in fact what i meant. copied part of a code from a different program where i was using a string. my bad.
You're right, not closing the descriptor was getting me stuck. However I'm now getting another problem. The amount of data is correct but "wc" is now returning 0 0 0. I'm guessing it's because i took the data from the descriptor... I probably can't solve this without using another fork and pipe

Comment: Yes, by reading the data, you "took it out". What you can do is to read it from the buffer and then writing it back to another pipe, no need of another fork. This other pipe will be the pipe to dup. The easiest way to do so is to use the for(;;) I wrote above

Comment: about your last edit, the reason i didn't use an array was because i'm not sure if the amount of data read would be bigger then my array and that could give me some other weird problems.

Comment: It worked with just another pipe like you said. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Glad it helped you :)